# gpx data shows additional lines in QGIS (using GPS Tools)

Tags: qgis, gpx, gpstools

I created several shapefiles two years ago (lines, MultiLineString, CRS 25833) in QGIS 3.4. standalone. Operating System: Windows 10.

Now, I converted the shapefiles into gpx files (merged the data before if necessary, used the export function save as gpx, CRS WGS 84, deselected all fields, force GPS track: yes).

If I use the option: show saved data on map the data appears correctly. The same if I import the gpx files in Garmin GPSmap 64s. All fine.

But, if I import the gpx file into QGIS using “gps tools” and select tracks, then in most of the files appear additional lines (just random straight lines, sometimes they connect the ends).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/64EyN.jpg]

Tried QGIS 3.10., same results.

If I create a new vector layer and draw new lines, then there will be shown no additional lines. So, it could be an issue with these two years old shapefiles, but they look normal.

How can I check and/or fix the gpx data (or shapefile data)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *"gps tools"*, but does it have an option called something like 'Close track' (or path/line in place of track). If so, that is what is probably causing it.

Comment: "gps tool" is a plugin for QGIS for e. g. laoding gpx data into QGIS. Unfortunately, I can't see an option to close a track.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Is there perhaps an alternative way of closing a track?

Comment: What happens if you just drag them into the map canvas from your file directory, instead of using the plugin to import them?

Comment: Thank you. This works. So it must be the GPS-Tool, which is causing the additional lines. Strange.